# Coveo for sitecore index rebuild not showing unites proceed in log

Tags: sitecore, coveo

I am on sitecore 8.1(160302) with Coveo for Sitecore 81 4.0(895).

When rebuild index for Coveo_web_index and Coveo_master_index in indexing manager,
at the end I will see the result window showing the number of the units been processed.

However in log file I don't see the units been processed.

[image]

Anyone else has the same issue?

Comment: Are you able to see search results?

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a display issue.

It does not cause any problem, the items have been processed.